# "Unconfigure" oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-rac

I have an Oracle 11g RAC installation which I want to "unconfigure".

This is a cloned machine which has an Oracle 11g RAC installation. I want to "reset" it (drop databases, configuration etc and keep only the binaries) so that I can re-configure it according to my new requirements.

Oracle provides instructions on how to [Unconfigure Oracle Clusterware without removing binaries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cwsol/unconfiguring-oracle-clusterware-without-removing-binaries.html), which as far as I understand refers only to the CRS (and I am not sure it applies to 11g).

However I want the same procedure for the database too. Is there anything similar?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A database alone (without Grid Infrastructure) has configuration data that you can simply delete or remove from text files.

(Unless it is Windows, where Windows services are defined for the database instances).

When using RAC (or Oracle Restart), some database configuration is stored in the OCR of Grid Infrastructure. After you deconfigure that, you can just get rid of the remaining things, but none of the below is absolutely necessary.

- remove entries of the database from `/etc/oratab`
- remove database related files from `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`
- remove database related entries from `sqlnet.ora`, `tnsnames.ora`
- remove remaining files and directories related to the database: `$ORACLE_BASE/admin/${DB_NAME}`, `$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/${DB_UNIQUE_NAME}`
- remove database files from their location if you did not use ASM for them

These are just the typical default locations, but some of them may be stored somewhere else, depending on your configuration.